# Given a string remove all the special characters except hyphen and count number of words

Tags: java, arrays, string

Given a string "this is high-tech job market in which? we make. careers"
I have to remove all special characters except hyphen and count number of words in a string so output should be 10 in this case.
I have written below program but it did not pass the test cases.

```
public int countWords(String str) {
    if(str.isEmpty() || str==null)
       return 0;
    String replacedString = str.replaceAll(["^a-zA-Z0-9- ]","");
    String[] arrWords = replacedString.split("\\s+");
    return arrWords.length;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Unit Test?

Comment: It was online compiler question, I could not see exactly which test case failed

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex, `[\p{Punct}&&[^-]]` where `\p{Punct}` stands for a punctuation. If you want to replace everything other than alphabets, digits, hyphen and space, you can use the regex, `[^\p{Alnum}\s-]` where `\p{Alnum}` stands for an [alphanumeric character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "this is high-tech job market in which? we make. careers";

        String[] arr = str.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^-]]", "").split("\\s+");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        int count = arr.length;

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[this, is, high-tech, job, market, in, which, we, make, careers]
10
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the null / empty condition should be in the opposite order:

```
    if(str==null || str.isEmpty())
```

Do you understand why? (Hint: Java evaluation is lazy)

Additionally, does a "-" (minus) should be removed or not?

Comment: `[^]` is the RegEx negation, so the RegEx means "replace all except"

Comment: I know what a regex notation is :) You may Look at the definition of the author "remove all special characters". so I asked whether a "-" count as special charater or not? he used it as exception (i.e - it's not a special charater and the value in this case is 10), so I wanted to verify.

Comment: Oh, "hyphen" is missing from the question body but is in headline. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to count 10 words from your code.
You replace your string if it's a non-word (`\W`) and you make an exception for hyphen.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "this is high-tech job market in which? we make. careers";
        myString = myString.replaceAll("[\\W&&[^\\-]]", " ");
        String[] arrWords = myString.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(arrWords.length);
    }

}
```

The advantage of using `\W` is that it includes all unicode punctuation.

For exemple if you have these characters `‘ „`, `\p{Punct}` won't work.

Here is an alternative using `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` if you need it :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "this is high-tech job market ‘ „ in which? we make. careers";
        String[] arrWords2 = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}&&[^-]]|\\s", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).split(myString);
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrWords2));
        arrayList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("",null));
        System.out.println(arrayList);
        System.out.println(arrayList.size());
    }

}
```